# Problem in displaying the google maps API

Tags: ios, google-maps

when i use the google maps API, all went fine, however, i notice that the map contains some controls (buttons) which are not operational, this is a screenshot of what i am talking about :
[image]

The three buttons on the top right and the arrows on the top left are not operational.
My relevant code is this :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&hl=fr&output=mobile&om=5",latUtilisateur,longUtilisateur,latStation,longStation];

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Can i remove it from the map?

Comment: show your html file with your map object?

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using `MapKit`?
Instead of adding a `UIWebView`, you can add a `MKMapView` and center to your geocoord. It's made by Apple (public API) so it's very smooth and works just like all other applications on iOS that are using maps.

Comment: Hi, i thought about UIWebView because i have tried to trace itinerary between two points on the map, as i have noticed, the mapkit doesn't offer this feature, am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is how you want to display google maps in iPhone, using a result of web url? Because there is a separate map view (Map Kit). A classic iphone google map should not have those buttons on top left. A map works with pinch and scroll!